# How to get the difference in days between two JDateChooser objects

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I'd like to know the difference in days (excluding time).

These are my `JDateChooser` objects:

```
JDateChooser dateChooser_in = new JDateChooser();
JDateChooser dateChooser_out = new JDateChooser();
```

I tried to convert it to `Date` first, but I don't know how to so.

Comment: Use Java 8's Time API or JodaTime

Comment: To get date from `JDateChooser` use `Date date =  dateChooser.getDate();`

Answer (score 1):

`JDateChooser` has a `getDate` method which returns a `java.util.Date`.  Once you have that, it's just a matter of using Java 8's Time API or JodaTime to calculate the difference

## Java 8

```
LocalDateTime from = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateChooser_in.getDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime to = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(dateChooser_out.getDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

Duration d = Duration.between(from, to);
System.out.println(d.toDays());
```

## Joda-Time

```
LocalDate from = LocalDate.fromDateFields(dateChooser_in.getDate());
LocalDate to = LocalDate.fromDateFields(dateChooser_out.getDate());

System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(from, to).getDays());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How can i set it to text field? I tried it using the Java 8

Comment: @STEPHENYAO Of the `JDateChooser`?  Have you considered using `setDate`?

Comment: I have a textfield named textFieldTotalDays ,  I tried this textFieldTotalDays.setText(d.toDays()) , it doesnt work

Comment: `String.valueOf(d.toDays())`

Answer (score 0):

If you have two dates, the number of days can be calculated as:

```
Date date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
Date date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
long diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
System.out.println ("Number of days: " + TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

See [TimeUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) documentation for more info.

Comment: Why, why, why do people insist on doing this when there perfectly good date/time libraries available :( - Using `Calendar` to loop between the dates would be more preferable to this.  This won't take into consideration the joys of century, millennium or other boundaries, day light savings, leap years/seconds and wrath of other issues with date/time ...

Comment: I do not like Joda library.

Comment: Then you like incorrect data? Use `Calendar` if you don't like JodaTime, use Java 8's Time API if your don't like JodaTime, use just about any other time/date API, hell, use `Date4J`, but not millisecond maths!

Comment: Why not? Does not the library code will use milliseconds ?

Comment: BUT, it doesn't take into consideration the rules governing how time is adjusted over the century and millennium boundaries or things like day light savings or leap years/seconds.  It's generally an inaccurate measurement.  There is not exactly 365 days in a year nor 24 hours in a day nor 60 seconds in a minute...

Comment: No, in most cases, this code will blow up in your face.  Even if you're just trying to calculate the number of minutes between a few hours, you could cross a day light savings boundary...

Comment: Does not Java `Date` class takes care of the leap year problem? The daylight saving time does not make any difference when calculating days ( what is one hour to 24 hours) and considering `JDateChooser` gets date with zero time.

Comment: When been formatted yes, but it's still just a container of milliseconds.  As a general rule, millisecond calculations are a bad idea and get present way to much, when there are better alternatives available